# LibGDX Scene2D a different way of implementing a GUI scale setting other than multiplying everything by a constant?

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d

I have a bunch of UI elements for my game. I have an inventory, HUD, hotbar, in-game menu etc. Now I want to scale these based on a setting. I import the settings from a file and basically put it in a global variable, which can be used by the UI elements. Currently the way I'm going about this is multiplying every position, width and height of all children of the UI Stages by this global variable. This isn't very practical or maintainable, though. So I was wondering if there's another way to go about this? I figured maybe there is a built in scaling option? Sadly I wasn't able to find anything about this online since the search term "scaling" results in a ton of different, more common, questions/solutions.

Comment: You can scale the Viewport's world width and world height instead of all the UI component positions and dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Scene2D` you probably have a root `Actor` that contains all the other UI components. You just need to set the scale property to the root `Actor`.

```
float scale = ...; //XY scale
Actor root = ...;
root.setScale(scale);
```